# Audio Service displaying RED underline

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Recently I decided to up my skills by building an app with Audio features.
so I came across these cool Dependencies **just_audio** and **audio_service**, but the usage of it is showing up errors and I can't figure out what is wrong.

***Below is my code***

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:audio_service/audio_service.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

MediaControl playControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_play_arrow',
  label: 'Play',
  action: MediaAction.play,
);
MediaControl pauseControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_pause',
  label: 'Pause',
  action: MediaAction.pause,
);
MediaControl skipToNextControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_next',
  label: 'Next',
  action: MediaAction.skipToNext,
);
MediaControl skipToPreviousControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_skip_previous',
  label: 'Previous',
  action: MediaAction.skipToPrevious,
);
MediaControl stopControl = MediaControl(
  androidIcon: 'drawable/ic_action_stop',
  label: 'Stop',
  action: MediaAction.stop,
);

class AudioPlayerTask extends BackgroundAudioTask {
  //
  var _queue = <MediaItem>[];
  int _queueIndex = -1;
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
  late AudioProcessingState _skipState;
  late bool _playing;
  bool get hasNext => _queueIndex + 1 < _queue.length;
  bool get hasPrevious => _queueIndex > 0;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => _queue[_queueIndex];

  late StreamSubscription<AudioPlaybackState> _playerStateSubscription;
  late StreamSubscription<AudioPlaybackEvent> _eventSubscription;

  @override
  void onStart(Map<String, dynamic> params) {
    super.onStart(params);
  }

  @override
  void onPlay() {}

  @override
  void onPause() {}

  @override
  void onSkipToNext() async {}

  @override
  void onSkipToPrevious() {}

  void skip(int offset) async {}
  @override
  Future<void> onStop() async {}

  @override
  void onSeekTo(Duration position) {}

  @override
  void onClick(MediaButton button) {}

  @override
  Future<void> onFastForward() async {}

  @override
  Future<void> onRewind() async {}

  _handlePlaybackComplete() {
    //
  }
}
```

**Dependency of Interest**

```
just_audio: ^0.9.7
audio_service: ^0.17.1
http: ^0.13.3
```

***What am Getting***

[image]

[image]

[image]

From the Above image, you will see that the following are underline in red colors
*`AudioPlaybackState`*, *`void onStart()`*, *`void onPlay()`*, *`void onPause()`*, *`void onSkipToNext()`*, *`void onSkipToPrevious()`*, *`void onSeekTo(Duration position)`*, *`void onClick(MediaButton button)`*

> The Problem is that I can't import them into the code, taking for example **AudioPlaybackState** is not even among the list of keywords showing up

When I Hover my mouse around the Red Underline, i got the following

> The name 'AudioPlaybackState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a
> type argument.

and got the following for each respective override when I hover around it

> 'AudioPlayerTask.onStart' ('void Function(Map<String, dynamic>)')
> isn't a valid override of 'BackgroundAudioTask.onStart' ('Future
> Function(Map<String, dynamic>?)').

***What have done so far***

1. Have Upgrade my Flutter
2. Invalidate and Restart
3. Flutter Clean

Despite all that I have done, the issue still persists.

***please what am not doing well?***

Comment: What is the error that appears to you when you hover your mouse on the red line ?

Comment: thanks, I just edit the question,

Comment: when I hover the red line, I got  **The name 'AudioPlaybackState' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.**

Comment: and got this for the respective override

**'AudioPlayerTask.onStart' ('void Function(Map<String, dynamic>)') isn't a valid override of 'BackgroundAudioTask.onStart' ('Future<void> Function(Map<String, dynamic>?)').**

Comment: I think the problem is the return type of the overridden functions. They all return futures where you just return void. Please try and change that.

Comment: @malrok44, that's not the issue

Answer (score 0):

After much googling, I found the right answer on a medium article post,
here is the link [Click here](https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d)

My best guess is that after the upgrade in the dependencies most of the term was no longer used.

it's working now